# My css animation doesnt work when i run js function classList.add

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a `div` with some `class` and `height 0px` and on clicking something, I run `classList.add` to add the `class` where `height` is `150px` (popup). When the function adds the class, `div` is supposed to make an animation from `height: 0px` to `height: 150px`.
Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```js
function issPopup() {
  var ist = document.getElementById("ist");
  iss.classList.toggle("istopen");

}
```

```css
@keyframes isani1 {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 130px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes isani1 {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 130px;
  }
}

.inputsubmittextdiv.istopen {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 130px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: isani1 1s;
  animation: isani1 1s;
}

.inputsubmittextdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="ist" class="inputsubmittextdiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: How should we help you when there's no CODE?!!!

Comment: Can yout create a jfiddle or codepen with your code and share?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like the following:

```js
function addClass(elem) {
  elem.classList.add('istopen');
}
//here are you are basically telling your onCLick event to add the .istopen class whenever "something" is clicked. 
//you can do the same when you hover over something etc.
```

```css
.istopen {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 130px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: isani1 1s;
  animation: isani1 1s;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="ist" onclick="addClass(this)"> Something
</div>
```